# Filter Data for 30 months using subquery with INTERVAL function in Teradata

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata, intervals

I would like to filter out the data using a sub query in the interval function

Following is the query i use

```
SEL * FROM my_table WHERE MY_DATE < CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL '30' MONTH;
```

The above query works, However i want to parameterize the period '30' using a sub query. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you mean by parameterize here? user should prompt for value? why you need sub query?

Comment: I don't think Teradata will allow you to do this with a sub-query (besides a sub-query will give you a result-set, not a single value).  I think you'll need to create a Stored Procedure to be able to do something like this.  I have seen stored-procedures that first construct the query and then run it.  Unfortunately I don't know the specifics of how it was done.

Comment: I do remember it used a query the collated a number of strings to eventually make the output query, e.g. "SELECT 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_DATE < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL ''' || tbl1.int_amt || ''' MONTH;' FROM db1.tbl1" then run it in the next step of the Stored Proc somehow.  I don't remember how it then ran that query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use interval calculations with year/month as it will fail, e.g. `DATE '2016-12-31' + INTERVAL '30' MONTH` results in `2019-06-31` (according to Standard SQL) which obviously doesn't exist.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE MY_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, (SELECT -col FROM tab));
```

If `col` is actually an INTERVAL you need to cast it to an INT.